# Solve Euler Project #9 only mathematically - Pythagorean triplet

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

**The "Euler Project" problem 9 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=9) asks to solve:**

$a^2$ + $b^2$ = $c^2$
a + b + c = 1000

I find answers solving it with brute-force and programmatically, but **is there a way to solve the problem ONLY mathematically? Can someone help, please?**

```
Problem as explained in Project Euler website:

A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which,

a^2 + b^2 = c^2
For example, 3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 52.

There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.

Find the product abc.
```

Comment: what do you know about triples in general ...

Comment: I might call what you're asking for "solving manually" instead. After all, the programming solution is certainly a mathematical one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint** [Euclid's parameterization of the Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) (*Elements*, [Book X, Proposition XXIX](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookX/propX29.html)) is:
$$a = k (m^2 - n^2), \qquad b = 2 k m n, \qquad c = k (m^2 + n^2),$$
where $m > n > 0$ and $m, n$ coprime and not both odd.

Substituting in our condition gives
$$1000 = a + b + c = 2 k m (m + n),$$ and clearing the constant leaves $$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad 500 = k m (m + n) . \qquad (\ast)$$
Now, notice that (1) $500 = 2^2 5^3$ has only two distinct prime factors, and (2) since $m$ and $n$ are coprime, so are $m$ and $m + n$.

> So, one of $m, m + n$ must be one of $1, 2, 4$ (in fact one of $2, 4$, since $m > n > 0$ implies $m + n > m > 1$) and the other must be one of $1, 5, 25, 125$. Because $m + n > m$, we must have $m \in \{2, 4\}$, and so $m + n < 2 m \leq 8$. Thus, $m + n = 5$, and $2 m > m + n = 5$ implies $m \geq 3$, leaving $m = 4$ as the only possibility. So, $n = 1, k = 25$, and $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{(a, b, c) = (375, 200, 425)}} .$$

Comment: Yours is nicer than mine.

Comment: I managed to streamline the part of the proof in the spoiler box a little more.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: Cheers, Ian!$\!$

Answer (score 3):

The triplets are all of the form
$a=u(n^2-m^2),
b=2umn,
c=u(n^2+m^2)
$
with $n > m$
so
$a+b+c
=u(2n^2+2mn)
=2un(n+m)
$.

We must have
$n > m$.

Therefore
$500
=un(n+m)
$.

If
$500 = rst
$
with
$s < t$
then
$u = r,
n = s,
n+m = t
$
so
$m = t-n
=t-s
$.

We must have
$n > m$
so
$s > t-s$
or
$s < t < 2s$.

Playing around a bit,

$500 = 1*20*25$,
so,
swapping $m$ and $n$,
$u = 1, m = 5,
n=20
$
and the sides are
$20^2-5^2 = 375 = 25\ 15,
2\ 20\ 5 = 200 = 25\ 8,
20^2+5^2 = 425 = 25\ 17
$.

Answer (score 3):

If the Pythagorean parameterization is a little advanced, be rest assured that it is unnecessary.  One can simply rewrite the condition as:
$$c = 1000 - a - b$$
And simply substitute into the Pythagorean Theorem as:
$$a^2+b^2=(1000-a-b)^2 = 1,000,000 + a^2+b^2 - 2000a-2000b+2ab$$
We can easily rewrite this as:
$$ab - 1000a-1000b + 500,000 = 0$$
Now we employ Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick to "factor" this as:
$$(a-1000)(b-1000) = 500,000$$
Now both $a$ and $b$ are less than $1000$, so perhaps it would be better to have this written in the form:
$$(1000-a)(1000-b) = 500,000$$
In other words, we are seeking two factors, both less than a thousand, that multiply to $500,000$.

There are many ways to finish, including some simple guess-and-checking.  Fortunately, there is a relatively clean finish.  One could potentially now observe that $500,000 \approx 490,000 = 700^2$, so perhaps our factors are around $700$.  This is a decent ballpark to start with.  Now, one could observe that our factors perhaps could have been $500$ and $1000$, but unfortunately one of these is not less than $1000$.  We could instead say that our factors must be between $500$ and $1000$.  If our factors were to be $F_1,F_2$, we can write:
$$500 < F_1,F_2 < 1000$$
We now try to tighten this bound, keeping in mind that *both* factors must satisfy it.  Firstly, we note that $500,000 = 2^5 \cdot 5^6$.  It would be quite ridiculous if, say, $F_1$ were to have no factors of $5$, for then the maximum value it could have be would be $32$, which is for sure outside of these bounds.  So for each of our factors, we can say that they contain a factor of 5.  Donating our two factors of 5, we're left with $2^5 \cdot 5^4$, and they satisfy some new bounds:
$$100 < \frac{F_1}{5},\frac{F_2}{5} < 200$$
Continuing, it would be equally ridiculous if $\frac{F_1}{5}$ had no factors of 5 either, since $32$ is still outside of these bounds.  Donating an additional two factors of 5, we're left with $2^5 \cdot 5^2$ to work with, and the following bounds:
$$20 < \frac{F_1}{5^2},\frac{F_2}{5^2} < 40$$
At this point, we can stop with the reduction, and see that *by inspection*, we have both $32$ and $25$ satisfying this inequality, and so $32*25 = 800$ and $25*25 = 625$ would be our factors.  Some simple thought can tell us that really, this is the *only* solution that can satisfy these bounds.  Namely, if within the last obtained inequality, we somehow found another two numbers that satisfied it that multiplied to $2^5 \cdot 5^2$, then surely one of these numbers would be a $10$.  But $10$ does not satisfy the bounds, and multiplying it by either some 2s or 5s will jump over the whole interval $(20,40)$, so no such alternate solution can exist.  Now, the rest of the problem is routine.  We write:
$$1000 - a = 800$$
$$1000 - b = 625$$
And so $a = 200$ and $b = 375$.

Comment: Nitpick, please don't call the diophantine equation $a^2+b^2=c^2$ the Pythagorean Theorem. They might have the same equation, but are unrelated in this case since you're not invoking any geometry.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that all primitive Pythagorean triples (i.e with no common factors) is of the form $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ for relatively prime $m$ and $n$ where one is even and the other is odd.

Based on that, you are looking for $m$ and $n$ such that $$(m^2-n^2)+2mn+(m^2+n^2)=2m^2+2mn=2m(m+n)$$ is a factor of $1000$.

Comment: Which then restricts $m,n$ because $m,n$ being 1 mod 3, force divisibility by 3. $m$ being 2 mod 3 Also can't work with $n$ 1 mod 3, and neither can both being 0 mod 3.  that cuts down the work.

Answer (score 1):

Given perimeter: $\qquad P=(m^2-n^2 )+2mn+(m^2+n^2 )=2m^2+2mn\qquad $ If we solve for $n$, we can find if there exists one or more $m,n$ combinations for a Pythagorean triple with that perimeter. Any value of $m$ that yields an integer $n$ gives us such an $m,n$ combination. We let:

$$n=\frac{P-2m^2}{2m}\quad where \quad \biggl\lceil\frac{\sqrt{P}}{2}\biggr\rceil\le m \le \biggl\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{P}{2}}\biggr\rfloor$$
Here, the lower limit ensures that  $m>n$ and the upper limit insures that $n>0$. For example:

$$P=1000\implies \biggl\lceil\frac{\sqrt{1000}}{2}\biggr\rceil =16\le m \le \biggl\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{1000}{2}}\biggr\rfloor=22$$

In this range, we find that only $20$ is a factor of $1000$ and the only value of $m$ that yields and integer $n$. We find that $m=20\implies n=5$, and, using Euclid's formula $F(m,n)$, we have $F(20,5)=(375,200,425)$. Then, the product, as I understand it, is $$A\times B\times C=375\times200\times425=31875000.$$